# Can I test to see if an application is avaliable to handle an intent, without starting it?

Tags: android, android-intent

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out if there is an application to handle the market intent, but I'd like a general case solution.

I know if you do something like this, you can tell if there is an application available to handle the intent. I'm trying to do something that doesn't actually launch the intent. Any ideas on what I might do?

```
try
{
    String strURL="market://details?id="+thePackage;
    Intent the_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL));
    the_intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(the_intent)

}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    String strUrl="https://play.google.com/store/search?c=apps&q="+thePackage;

    Intent the_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUrl));
    the_intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(the_intent)
}
```

What I want is a solution that doesn't involve actually starting the activity. There's a few reasons why I want to do this, but I imagine I'm not the only one to have thought of a reason for this, it seems like there must be a way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` or `resolveActivity()`. The former will return a `List` of things that match an `Intent` to be used with `startActivity()`. The latter will return `null` for no matches or an `Intent` which is the "best match" (which could be the chooser activity if there is more than one match).

Comment: How `Intent.resolveActivity()` is different from `PackageManager.resolveActivity()`?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad: They are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a practical example from CommonWare's answer.

```
String strURL="market://details?id="+thePackage;
Intent the_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL));
the_intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
Log.v(TAG,""+_context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(the_intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
if (_context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(the_intent,0).size()==0)
{
    String strUrl="https://play.google.com/store/search?c=apps&q="+thePackage;
    the_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUrl));
    the_intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
}
```

Comment: Your code has bugs, at least according to the docs. For `queryIntentActivities()`, "if there are no matching activities, an empty list is returned." You are checking for `null`, not an empty list. Also, AFAIK, the second parameter to `queryIntentActivities()` is either `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` or `0`, not `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: Ahhh, that explains why my code wasn't working... I'll fix it, thanks!